# "The user is not enabled for live streaming" Error

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api

I've been struggling quite a bit to solve the this issue. Basically, I'm just trying to connect to my youtube channel and get a list of future and past live broadcasts from my PHP based application. I was able to create a service account on the api console and it seems to be working fine now (as I've had some oauth authentication errors before) but now, I'm receiving this error in my error log:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet&mine=true:
(403) The user is not enabled for live streaming.' in etc...
```

My youtube account is associated with my personal @gmail.com account. I'm assuming that somehow I have to add the @developer.gserviceaccount.com to my youtube channel but even though I've tried to find any instructions for this, I was not able to find. I have live streaming enabled on my personal gmail account and also have some test events there.

Would appreciate and help in this matter please. Thanks!

Comment: Youtube does not support service accounts, unfortunately, and there aren't currently any plans to allow that. Your only option is to use oAuth2 and set up live streaming for users on the fly as they authenticate to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but in my case it turned out to be that the account somehow had 2 accounts:

- a page with a strange page-id@pages.plusgoogle.com and
- a normal Google email account user@gmail.com).

On top of that, I had issues with not renewing the access token: e.g sending an old access token.

Make sure you try the 2 sub accounts; one must have the videos under it. If you choose the wrong one, then you get that error above.