# YouTube Streaming API says user is not enabled for live streaming

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using [Google's YouTube API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.liveBroadcasts.list) ([alternate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#try-it)) to look up information on [an arbitrary streaming broadcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_RrkyIOVhg) belonging to someone else.

No matter what I put into the `id` field, I always get back

```json
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
            "reason": "liveStreamingNotEnabled",
            "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming.",
            "extendedHelp": "https://www.youtube.com/features"
         }],
         "code": 403,
         "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming."
    }
}
```

This seems ridiculous, considering that the video is plainly streaming.

It occurred to me that I might have misunderstood the instructions for the `id` field, so I've tried a couple different possibilities. These include...

- The Channel ID (`UCHZoP1Jy-g_h3sqzScrOEwQ`)
- The User ID (`GWTV`)
- The Video ID (`J_RrkyIOVhg`)

...each to no avail.

How can I ask a channel about its live streaming videos? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22310972/241211) would have answered that in the past, but the comments indicate that the answer no longer works. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24218545/241211) wasn't really any help either.

#### Edit 2022

If you are looking for how to get streaming state and currently streaming video from an arbitrary channel, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32454238/241211) and particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026382/241211).

Comment: Hello Michael, I am getting the same error "The user is not enabled for the  live streaming". when i am running the sample code of "CreateBroadcast.java" file. How did you resolve that. Could you please help me out ?

Comment: @Rajeev I can get you a little further, but I didn't ultimately get this working. If you enable live streaming on your own account, you can get past _that error,_ but when I did that, I [still couldn't get any data.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32380110/241211)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**Errors** heading of the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#errors) has this interesting chart:

| Error Type | Error Detail | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `insufficientPermissions` | `insufficientLivePermissions` | The request is not authorized to retrieve the live broadcast |
| `insufficientPermissions` | `liveStreamingNotEnabled` **(This is the error I'm getting.)** | The user that authorized the request is not enabled to stream live video on YouTube. The user can find more information at https://www.youtube.com/features |

which implies that because *my* account is not enabled for live streaming, I can't look at anyone *else's* live stream information in the API, even if I can pull it up in the browser. This seems kind of arbitrary, but the error I got in the original question turned out to be the permissions problem.

Note that even after enabling live streaming for *myself,* [I still can't get useful data for *third-party streams*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32380110/241211) because **[Google does not allow checking the Live Streaming API for users that are not you.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644218#comment3)**

Comment: In my case it happends when the google/youtube account is not fully activated. try to go to https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard_splash and  check if you can enable streaming.

Comment: @Michaelcomelately - what was the permissions problem that you said was the cause? I'm getting the same liveStreamingNotEnabled, but my livestreaming is enabled and has been for several years.

Comment: @aim Are you trying to fetch your own feed or [someone else's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32380110/241211)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when trying to get Youtube Livestream status.

In my case I'm using 'Youtube Brand Account' and it's worth trying to switch the brand account as the authorized user. That worked fine.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this we need to enable live stream in studio > setting > channel > feature > enable broadcast

Live stream services will work after 24 hours

Comment: Broadcast is alreay enabled in **Advanced Features**,  then why its not working?