# YouTube Streaming API returns no results

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using [Google's YouTube API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.liveBroadcasts.list) ([alternate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list#try-it)) to look up information on streaming broadcasts.

No matter what I put into the  various "Filter" fields (`id`, `broadcastStatus`, `mine`), I always get back something like

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#liveBroadcastListResponse",
    "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/1a_a-Wfcf01HR1raH5I2Na5kI1o\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 0,
        "resultsPerPage": 5
    },
    "items": [
    ]
} // (The etag changes each time)
```

This seems ridiculous, considering that [someone somewhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_RrkyIOVhg) is demonstrably streaming.

It makes sense that `mine=true` doesn't return any results because I've never broadcasted anything, but `broadcastStatus=all` should give me *something.*

What is going wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue. I'm fairly certain it was working fine as recently as a few days ago and I'm sure it was working a few months ago. Maybe you should file a bug for it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list).

Comment: I tried liveBroadcasts.list while I was streaming a live event and it would only show my broadcast. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to [a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644218?pli=1) issued by [DaImTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto), Google has responded by telling us that [we are not permitted](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644218#comment3) to see live broadcasts by other users.

> **ma…@google.com** <ma…@google.com> [#3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644218#comment3) Jun 25, 2018 07:11 PM
>
> *Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)*
>
> The Live Streaming API only permits you to list the live broadcasts of the authenticated user.

However, an answer to a similar question can retrieve currently streaming events by [parsing the `href` attribute of `<link rel="canonical" />`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70026382/241211) on the channel page.

Comment: I've been searching for a resolution for weeks, and this continues to be the only solution I've been able to find that reliably works as intended. However, each page returns over 400k of data. If I'm searching through multiple channels, that's an enormous server load. Any thoughts of how to mitigate the sheer data size?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I've encountered the same issue yesterday and it seems that I'm missing the `broadcastType` parameter.

Acceptable values are:

```
all – Return all broadcasts.
event – Return only scheduled event broadcasts.
persistent – Return only persistent broadcasts.
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list

So my final request looks like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id&mine=true&broadcastType=all
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, L. I notice, though, that you're trying to request your own broadcasts. I was hoping to get the status of someone _else's_ cast. For comparison, note [@not_a_bot's comments.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380110/youtube-streaming-api-returns-no-results/46360059#comment52633940_32380110)

Comment: I just had the same problem and setting a `broadcastType` fixed it! Very weird, as it is not listed as a required parameter in the docs and I would assume not setting it has the same effect as setting it to "all".
Thanks a lot for taking the time to write this response L!