# Youtube API call to check if a specific channel is streaming right now - rate limit

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to find ways to query the Youtube API to check if a channel (given its id) is streaming.

I'm using this call : `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
, which allow me to check the `liveBroadcastContent` variable, but it is a quite heavy call on the API quota (102 units) since it's using the search method for one "small" piece of data.

Do you know of any query that is more efficient in term of quota for that specific piece of information?

Comment: I'm inclined to say that currently, there's no other way to get the information in `liveBroadcastContent` if you only have the channel ID since the only other place that information would be exposed is in the `channels` resource, which it isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if channel is streaming right now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454238/how-to-check-if-channel-is-streaming-right-now)