# Push Notifications for new live broadcasts via PubSubHubbub

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api, websub

I would like to receive notifications on new live broadcasts of YouTube channels. As described in [YouTube v3 Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) I've set up a public accessible PubSubHubbub callback server and subscribed to my own YouTube channel where I've tested the callbacks for "normal videos" and for live broadcasts. The subscription returned a `HTTP 204` and I am getting pings for

- new videos
- changes of videos
- deletion of vides

However I do not get a Ping when a live broadcast starts. It is visible on the YouTube channel, you can view it, use the chat, the live dashboard says everything is fine. So that part is okay. But there is no ping to the PubSubHubbub callback server for new live broadcasts.

However if I change the title or the description in the [live dashboard](https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard) there is a ping for the current live broadcast.

For me it looks like that there is only a "onChange" for live broadcasts, but no "created" ping. Is there anything I can do to get the missing calls for new live broadcasts?

Regards,
wlami

Edit: Once I stop the live broadcast I get two update Pings once the broadcast has been processed and is shown as a video on the channel.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

[Youtube Notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) via PubSubHubbub states in the docs that this is meant for:

- uploads a video updates
- a video's title updates
- a video's description

No mention of new live broadcast here.

Comment: That's right, but "a video's title updates" and "a video's description" also apply for current live broadcasts. So my assumption was that "uploads a video" is also covering live broadcasts.

Comment: Furthermore there are pings for deleted videos which are not mentioned at all on the linked page. Also the required verification of subscriptions is not mentioned, but part of PubSubHubbub. So the linked page doesn't look like it is the single source of truth about this API/service.