# Youtube data api retrieving and interacting with livechatmessages

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the youtube data api v3 via the javascript library. The list livebroadcasts call (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) gets broadcasts owned by the currently authenticated user (eg a user authenticated by oauth). I want to get a broadcast for a given channelid and then get its livechatid.

**Is it possible to get the livechatid of a live broadcast not owned by the current authed user?**

In my web app if there's a live broadcast for a given hardcoded channel id then I'll let people watch the broadcast via the embedded player and interact via a chat widget. This allows users to follow along with instruction while using the web app, and interact via chat.

Some initial investigation:

In the docs there're no parameters available to get around this problem in order to retrieve a livebroadcast's livechatid, which is required to list and insert on the livechatmessages resource. You *can* use the search api resource to get the video id of the currently live broadcast (see [How to check if YouTube channel is streaming live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454238/how-to-check-if-youtube-channel-is-streaming-live/32463253#32463253)), but then you cannot use the `id` request parameter of the `list livebroadcast` request to get to the livechatid).

It *is* possible to use the livechatmessages resource for a livechatid that is not owned by the current authed user (tried this by getting hold of the livechatid as the owner account, then authing as a second account and using the api explorer). So once I get the livechatid I can do what's needed

I *could* use a server-side call to get hold of the current livechatid. That seems like the only good answer at this point, but is a bunch of extra work.

There's also the possibility to embed the youtube chat iframe (see https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549), but it appears that if you're not signed in then the chat frame will redirect the parent and not return to the site after sign in. Perhaps I can use the google client api to sign in, then load the iframe. This would be easier on front end work but sacrifices any customisability.

Comment: Using the client api to do oath before creating a chat iframe works fine. The chat iframe then loads and operates without any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering despite not addressing the central question, because I couldn't see any way to get the livechatid for another user.

As in comment:

> Using the client api to do oath before creating a chat iframe works fine. The chat iframe then loads and operates without any issues

One caveat to "without any issues" is that if I am signed in to youtube with account A (eg to broadcast) and then  in the same browser (chrome, not incognito) use my app then the google api client can claim that I'm not signed in, which is fine, but when I then select an account B during oauth sign in then the resulting iframed chat uses account A instead of account B. This makes some sense, since in the context of my app I never signed in via the google api with my app api key, but in the context of the youtube chat iframe I could be A or B, presumably. And using another browser this problem doesn't occur; there's only one account in play.