# Youtube api not returning my live stream

Tags: youtube-api

I have created a new google account, then I have enabled youtube live streaming and started to stream. I have app key and access token for my user, but http get request to `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams?part=snippet&access_token=MY_TOKEN&key=MY_KEY&mine=true` is returning zero results, meanwhile at the moment I have live stream.
What to do?

Comment: Could you figure out the problem? I'm having the same struggle at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try using [LiveStreams.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list) instead.  It returns a list of video streams that match the API request parameters. There's [an example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list#examples) for your code reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the saving clue in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360059/2072165%20%22this%20SO%20answer.). To receive the list, one has to explicitly provide the `broadcastType` parameter to the query.

> Acceptable values are:
>
> ```
> all – Return all broadcasts.
> event – Return only scheduled event broadcasts.
> persistent – Return only persistent broadcasts.
> ```

If you find this answer useful, please make sure to upvote the linked answer (as well). I just copy-pasted this.