# Has anyone found the workaround to the liveStreamingNotEnabled bug?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm having the same problem as a few other people have had here on SO. I can't find a single answer to the problem.

Even though live streaming is clearly enabled and I am streaming live, I get this error from the api.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
        "reason": "liveStreamingNotEnabled",
        "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://www.youtube.com/features"
     }],
     "code": 403,
     "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming."
  }
}
```

This user says that it turned out to be a permissions problem. However, his "answer" does not answer the question. Note that I am trying to use this to access information on my own stream, so I should be able to do it, or grant permission to my app. This question was asking how to access other people's stream data, while I want my own data, therefore not a duplicate. Thanks.

[YouTube Streaming API says user is not enabled for live streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362725/youtube-streaming-api-says-user-is-not-enabled-for-live-streaming)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YouTube Streaming API says user is not enabled for live streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362725/youtube-streaming-api-says-user-is-not-enabled-for-live-streaming)

Comment: Obviously a duplicate... but we need answers! : )

Comment: Welcome to stack we don't open new questions on the same topic you expand the existing questions or offer a bounty for an answer.    https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled  You may want to read this as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, thank you for your kind feedback. I thought a bit more, and I think actually my question is a little different from the one cited as duplicate. Therefore, I have edited my question a little as such.

Comment: After a bit of digging i am wondering if this could be qualified as bug.

Comment: It seems strange. The user (myself) clearly has live streaming enabled and yet it is telling that I have not, as others have pointed out.

Comment: You can check here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/0xoKC9YWEyQ/discussion

Comment: Remember that the youtube API is channel based. if a user has more then one channel your authentication is to the channel you click on at authentication time.   Are you sure you clicked on the correct channel?

Comment: In my case it happends when the google/youyube account is not correctly activated. When i go to https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard_splash it ask to activate the account for live streaming.

Answer (score 0):

> The YouTube Live Streaming API lets you **create, update, and manage live events** on YouTube. Using the API, you can schedule events (broadcasts) and associate them with video streams, which represent the actual broadcast content.

There for it would make sense for Google to insist that the authenticating account would have live streaming enabled.

I suggest you check that it is enabled for use with the API. [How to enable Live streaming](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/0xoKC9YWEyQ/discussion) Remember that the YouTube Api authentication is channel based.  When the user authenticated they had to pick a channel. Could they have picked one that did not have live streaming enabled.  Remember you will only have access to the one channel. If the user has more the one channel you will need to authenticate to each one.

While I do agree it seams strange if all you are going to do is list things that you would need to have live streaming enabled this appears to be the way the API works.

Personally i would like to see a public request that would let yous each for others live streams but again that doesn't appear to work with this api.  I have logged this as an issue / feature request.   [Live Streaming API: live streaming not enabled](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62644218)

[image]

Comment: "_Status:** Won't Fix (Intended behavior)_ The Live Streaming API only permits you to list the live broadcasts of the authenticated user."

Comment: Updated answer with image to the wont fix.